# Is Client side Batching supported in Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus?

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues, batching

Is Batching supported in Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus ? As in one of the microsoft doc links says it is not but i see lot of online examples ?

This microsoft docs link says it is not supported
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2

While this microsoft docs link has examples of Batching
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/messaging.servicebus-readme-pre#send-and-receive-a-batch-of-messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between implict and explicit batching. When using the SDK to send a batch that you constructed you are explicitly creating a batch message. That is supported.

Implicit batching means you can send individual messages using the SKD and the SDK will create a batch automatically when you send multiple individual messages in a given timeframe. This is done without you having to create a batch yourself. This is only supported on the legacy SDK.

Comment: So the example shown in this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/messaging.servicebus-readme-pre#send-and-receive-a-batch-of-messages is for explicit batching and not implicit batching. And Implicit batching is only supported in WindowsAzure.ServiceBus (Legacy one) and not in either of the two latest (i.e. Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus and Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus) ? Is my understanding correct ?